# long press view event

Tags: ios, objective-c

How could I detect the touch up event of a long press on view? For example, when the presses a view more than 5 seconds, and then touch up with their finger.

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` can be used for a fixed time press.

I have tried to use:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

but when the press more 2 seconds, this function will be called:

```
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Then it will never call `touchesEnded` again. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You want to detect a 2 second press? Why can't you use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Did you try using UILongPressGestureRecognizer and set the property minimumPressDuration?

Comment: Do not combine gesture recognizer with `touches...` methods!

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect situation for a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. This class is specifically designed for your situation and can be implemented as follows.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressOccured:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 5;
[self.window addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Comment: but when it press 10s, I could not get the touch up event.